# "Review Triage" screen should contain link to page which defines what a good question is and what is offtopic

Tags: feature-request

It would be very convenient for moderator to have questions guide at one click distance. Also different StackExchange sites have different recommended question topics. E.g. StackOverflow's "Review Triage" could reference https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic page.

Comment: If you doubt what to do during a review, just use the [Skip button](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip).

Comment: And/or use the Bookmark and Tab (or new window) features of your browser to keep them open for reference.

Comment: I often want to be able to easily click to make a comment to the poster on how to do one of these, when appropriate: 1) [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 2) [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and 3) [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  Having these canned and easily commented would be a significant help for all of the review queues.